# How do I create an Android background service application, for keeping the 3G connection always on?

Tags: android, service, android-service, 3g, background-application

I would like to create Android background service application that prevents to shut down the 3G    connection.
I will try to explain better, I've 4 Android tablets, and I need that my employees do not turn off the 3G connection.
Someone have an examples?
thanks beforehand

Comment: Is there an issue you're having with building this?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why a mobile data connection will shut down is because either:

- The user turned on airplane mode, or
- The user fussed around in Settings and screwed up an access point name or something

You cannot control either of these behaviors from an ordinary SDK app, except perhaps on a rooted device.

Comment: Or because the carrier sucks. Happens to me all the time :p

Comment: @keyser: I would interpret your issue as being that the mobile data connection is disconnected. There's nothing the OP can do about that either. However, the question is asking that "employees do not turn off the 3G connection", which is a separate matter.